# Ruby on Rails - has one or many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

So I have been thinking a lot how to build associations for my app, but every time I see a model from an angle, I see it doesn't make sense or not efficient.

I have three models: Tournament, RoundRobin and Elimination.
A tournament can be either a round_robin OR elimination OR both!
So round_robin or/and elimination belong to a tournament.

I am in a condition that the association I built is funny and doesn't make sense to me.

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :round_robins
    has_many :eliminations
end

class Elimination < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
end

class RoundRobin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
end
```

I have another model called Match. I dunno how to place it. Should it go under Tournament or RoundRobin and Elimination?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have just one table Tournament with column 'kind'. For example, if kind=0 that Tournament is a RoundRobin, if kind=1 that Tournament is a Elimination, if kind=2 that Tournament is both Elimination and RoundRobin.

Comment: Yea, I had it in my mind, but it is not rails-way to do it? Because when I want to update Tournament later on, I have to find RounRobin/Elimination and loop through them and update. It is not a good design for the long-run

Comment: I can't see any problem here. It is what you have now that is not rails-way.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since you aren't digging on STI, the alternative is having two types of Tournaments (round robin and Elimination that both belongs_to Tournament.

So in that case:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord:Base
 has_many :matches
 #attributes specific to any type of tournament: name, date, etc.
end

class RoundRobin < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :tournament

  #adds attributes specific to round robin tournaments
end
#etc
class Elimination < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :tournament
  #has attributes specific to elimination tournaments
end

class Match 
   belongs_to :tournament
end
```

So if you have a round_robin tournament it can get all the basic stuff from tournament:

```
round_robin = RoundRobin.find(1)
#get tourney name
puts round_robin.tournament.name
puts round_robin.tournament.match.team_one_name #allowing you to access the match as well...
```

If you wanted to you, could then have an attribute on Tournament that is called type (that let's you know which one it is). In rails these are traditionally strings. But in other languages, we typically used lookup_tables with foreign keys.

```
#to find all round_robins
tournaments = Tournament.find_by_type("round_robin")

tournmaments.each do |tourney|
  round_robin = RoundRobin.find_by_tournament_id(tourney.id)
end
#there are actually a bunch of different ways to query these:
round_robins = RoundRobin.all
tournaments = Tournament.joins(:round_robin).where("tournament_date > ?", date_lookup)
etc...
```

Comment: I had this in my mind too. I watch [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations) and figured out it won't work because a Tournament can consist of RoundRobin and Elimination. Plus, there would be a lot of nulls in the tables.

Comment: I don't thing there are problems with extraneous nulls in tables, that's generally the way STI works in Rails. However, I'm happy to give another answer that maybe more suited to what you are looking for.